# Openfire contact list sharing

Tags: xmpp, grouping, openfire, rostering

I installed openfire on CentOs and it uses external database for authentification and user list.

I managed groups based on a user table and a friend listing so that each user is also a group that is is an administrator and populated with users that are (friends).

External users and authentication works fine.

The issue is that the buddy list is only populated when is check "enable contact list group sharing openfire" on group administration.

I want to make this option always enabled so that user can see each other in their buddy list.

this is an existing issue [openfire issue](https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/31184)

Are there any possible solutions or alternatives.

**Edit:**

In other words, I want to avoid adding the following three lines to the ofGroupProp table:

```
name    sharedRoster.displayName    groupname

name    sharedRoster.groupList  

name    sharedRoster.showInRoster   onlyGroup
```

Comment: You have to get group members list? Please explain in brief.

Comment: I can get the group member list and set the admin correctly, i can see them in the admin console. The issue is i can't see the group members in the list to chat until i add those three lignes in the ofGroupProp table in openfire database

Comment: In iOS you can easily get group members using below function.

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchModeratorsList:(NSArray *)items

Comment: My problem is not getting group members, i can get them correctly, the issue is they are not able to chat until i share the group. It's a server issue not client, you can do nothing in iOS

Comment: Then all friends have to join particular group using 
"joinMultiUserChatRoom" method after success connect xmpp stream. After join group your friend will able to receive group messages.

Comment: Please read my architecture. Chat is one to one and each user is a moderator for his group a he can chat with his contacts which are members of his group. It's the openfire manner for external database for users and authentification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79133/discussion-between-mohamed-sadok-ben-jazia-and-parthpatel1105).